# Meteor template helper executed for each session object

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor template helper that is being called multiple times. The helper has session variables and I guess helper is executed when each session object is changed.

This is my helper:

```
Template.profile.helpers({
    listOfUsers: function (param1,param2,param3) {

   if(*if param 1/2/3 are not passed as parameters*)
   {
            var param1 = Session.get('param1');
            var param2 = Session.get('param2');
            var param3 = Session.get('param3');
   }
            /*This is the api call to get the data.
            Meteor.call('apiMethpod', param1, param2, param3, function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error occurred on receiving checks data on server. ", error);
                Session.set('apiData', "");
            } else {
                console.log("Checks data received on client side ");
                Session.set('apiData', result);
            }
            });
        return Session.get('apiData');
    }
});
```

This helper is also being called from an event :

```
Template.checkImages.events({
    'click .search': function(event){
/*Getting the values for params
var param1 = Session.get('param1');
var param2 = Session.get('param2');
var param3 = "Some value not from session object";
         Template.profile.__helpers.get("listOfUsers")(param1,param2,param3);
    }
});
```

When the event is triggered, parameters are getting passed to the helper and I am getting api response as expected for the first time. But the helper gets exceuted multiple times and now as it does not see the parameters it takes the values from session object.

I somehow wan the helper to execute only once when it is being called from the event.

Answer (score 0):

Does your HTML refer to `{{#each listOfUsers}}` anywhere? That would cause multiple updates and reactive updates based on changes in your 3 Session variables. You may wish to create a single session variable that's an object with `Session.set('myParams',{param1: value1, param2: value2, param3: value3})`.